# Access SQL Max-Function

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a question concerning MS Access queries involving these tables:

- tblMIDProcessMain ={ Process_ID,Process_Title,...}
- tblMIDProcessVersion = { ProcessVersion_ID, ProcessVersion_FK_Process, ProcessVersion_VersionNo, ProcessVersion_FK_Status, ...}
- tblMIDProcessVersionStatus = { ProcessVersionStatus_ID,ProcessVersionStatus_Value }

The tables store different versions of a process description. The "ProcessVersion_VersionNo" field contains an integer providing the version number. Now I would like to get for each process the highest version number thus the current version. If I do the following it kind of works:

```
SELECT tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel
       , Max(tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_VersionNo) AS CurrentVersion
FROM tblMIDProcessMain 
INNER JOIN tblMIDProcessVersion 
       ON tblMIDProcessMain.Process_ID = tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_FK_Process
GROUP BY tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel;
```

The query returns a recordset with each existing process_title and the respective max number of the version field. But as soon as I add other fields like "ProcessVersion_FK_Status" in the Select statement the query stops working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Jon

**Edit:**

To clarify things a little I added a simplified example

***Parent-Table:***

```
Process_ID  | Process_Title
----------------------------------
1           | "MyProcess"
2           | "YourProcess"
```

***Child-Table:***

```
Version_ID  | Version_FK_ProcessID  | Version_No    | Version_Status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1                     | 1             | "New"
2           | 2                     | 1             | "Discarded"
3           | 2                     | 2             | "Reviewed"
4           | 2                     | 3             | "Released"
```

***Intended Result:***

```
Title            | Max_Version_No   | Status
--------------------------------------------------------
MyProcess        | 1                | "New"
YourProcess      | 3                | "Released"
```

Comment: When you say 'the query stops working', are you receiving an error, or just not the results you want? Could you provide more information?

Comment: @Dan: If I add an additional field to the select clause I get an error saying this field is not part of the aggregated set (roughly translated from german). If I use an operator on the field I simply get the wrong results.

Comment: if you have: `select a, max(c) from tbl group by a`, then add another column, it needs to also appear in the group by: `select a, b, max(c) from tbl group by a, b` .. is that the issue you're having?

Comment: Yes that's basically what I want. But if I group by 'b' then the query returns all records because 'max(c)' is simply 'c' for every 'b' (at least I think that's the problem). I need a recordset that gets all entries from the parent table, calculates the max(c) of its children and then only returns fields from the same row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the example tables you updated your post with, this should work:

```
select process_title as Title
       , max_version.max_version_no
       , c.version_status as status
from (parenttable p
inner join (select max(version_id) as max_version_no, version_fk_process_id from childtable group by version_fk_process_id) max_version
    on p.process_id = max_version.version_fk_process_id)
inner join childtable c
    on max_version.max_version_no = c.version_id and max_version.version_fk_process_id = c.version_fk_process_id
```

Comment: This was it. I 've adapted your solution and it works now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are adding the new field to the 'Group By" clause?  If not, then you either must include in the 'Group By', or you must use one of the operators like "Max" or "First" etc.

Comment: Using 'Max' worked. I'm not quite sure why that is, but thank you very much.
Edit: My mistake. Didn't work unfortunately. Tried different operators but they all returned faulty results.

Comment: With operator: SELECT tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel, Max(tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_No) AS CurrentVersion, Max(tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_ID) AS MaxvonProcessVersion_ID
FROM tblMIDProcessMain INNER JOIN tblMIDProcessVersion ON tblMIDProcessMain.Process_ID = tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_FK_Process
GROUP BY tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel;

Comment: With Group clause: SELECT tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel, Max(tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_No) AS CurrentVersion, tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_ID
FROM tblMIDProcessMain INNER JOIN tblMIDProcessVersion ON tblMIDProcessMain.Process_ID = tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_FK_Process
GROUP BY tblMIDProcessMain.Process_Titel, tblMIDProcessVersion.ProcessVersion_ID;

Comment: oops - here is First:

Process_Titel CurrentVersion MaxvonProcessVersion_ID

End 1 4
Start 1 2

Second Query:

Process_Titel CurrentVersion ProcessVersion_ID
End 1 0
End 1 1
End 1 2
End 1 3
End 1 4
Start 1 0
Start 1 1
Start 1 2

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Both queries do execute but unlike you I get wrong results. The query simply adds a column with the first entries for each parent entry instead of adding the correct value from the row max(versionNo) was found in.